# xrdp gray screen

Tags: gala

I just did a fresh install of Elementary 0.3.2 in a virtual machine. I am trying to connect from a remote desktop (from the virtual host - windows 10). The login proceeds just fine until the screen loads - there's an xrdp grey screen that sits around for a few seconds before crashing.

I installed xrdp using apt-get without any issues.

Any suggestions for solving this problem?

Edit: I've since run apt-get upgrade. The grey screen is still there but now the remote desktop no longer crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Ubuntu 14.04, which is the provider of all the base packages. Some people claim that you can install xfce desktop, and change your ~/.xsession file to use it instead, but I have had no luck.

Here is the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1251281